# Redux Form wrapper around Field components

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have the following component structure:

```
<Selector label="A label">
  <Field name="radioField" component={SelectorItem} value="1">1</Field>
  <Field name="radioField" component={SelectorItem} value="2">2</Field>
</Selector>
```

So the Field components map to a custom radio button component I have, but the whole thing is made up of the top level Selector component and the SelectorItem components. How can I give the Selector wrapper component the error prop that is passed to the Field components? Will I need to pull it out of the state when I `connect`? I have looked at FieldArray in Redux Form but not sure if thats solving the issue Im having

Comment: Where doesn' the Selector  component get the prop from, its parent or redux store,

Comment: It doesn't at the moment the idea is that it is passed an error prop by the state to render the error state in the Selector component, but that error state is only available via props in the Field component, and i need it at a higher level

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by wrapping it again and iterating through the children:

```
class X extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Selector label={label} error={error}>
        {React.Children.map(children, ({ props = {} }) => (
          <SelectorItem
            {...this.props.input}
            value={props.value}
            checked={props.value === input.value}
          >
            {props.children}
          </SelectorItem>
        )}
      </Selector>
    );
  }
}
```